# Why did I get 100 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

Logged in this morning to see a notification that I had gained 100 rep, however, looking at my notifications and profile, the reason is not listed but it has definitely been added to the total.

So, how can I find out where this rep came from ?

Comment: +100? Looks like an association bonus on another site, mabye?

Comment: @guntbert That was my first thought too, however, I have not singed up to any SE sites in a while and was under the impression I only got +100 for the first three I joined (based on never getting rep after the first three), last one I joined was about 30 days ago, seems unlikely it would be that delayed in sending the rep.

Comment: joining a new site is **quite** easy using the Android app. It can happen *almost* inadvertently by voting on a post and then confirming.

Comment: That is correct, but the strange thing is, I have notifications for all my affiliation bonuses, but not this one. Do you think it could just of been delayed clearing in my account ?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a certain reputation on one stackexchange network site you get +100 reputation on every new network you join. The message for the reputation change is "You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network". If gives you certain privileges which makes sense if you understood stackexchange.

Once you cross that level of reputation you get the bonus on every network.